# How to extract values from column based on string value in other column?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, extract

I have a dataframe df:

```
x1   x2          x3
11   john     France-back
12   brad     france-present
13   alex     italy-back
14   chris    FrancE-forward
```

I want to extract unique values from column x1, if value in column x3 on same row has word france in it in any form (France, france, FrancE,...). So, desired result is:

```
x1
11
12
14
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grepl` with `ignore.case = TRUE`.

```
res <- data.frame(x1 = unique(df$x1[grepl('france', df$x3, ignore.case = TRUE)]))
res

#  x1
#1 11
#2 12
#3 14
```

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  filter(str_detect(x3, fixed('france', ignore_case = TRUE))) %>%
  distinct(x1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(grepl("france" x3, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%
  distinct(x1)
```